# javascript textarea lines count

Tags: javascript, opera

I need to count all lines in textarea.
My code:

```
function textareaCurLineNum(obj)
{
    return obj.value.split(/[\r\n]/g).length;
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome it works good.
In Opera it returns for one more.

I try this:

```
function textareaCurLineNum(obj)
{
    if (!/Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        return obj.value.split(/[\r\n]/g).length;
    } else {
        return obj.value.split(/[\r\n]/g).length-1;
    }
}
```

Now, if lines = 3, opera return 4, 4 lines - 6, 5 lines - 8.
Where is a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets contains set of symbols, not a sequence. split by \n in regexp.

```
function textareaCurLineNum(obj)
{
    if (!/Opera/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        return obj.value.split(/\n/g).length;
    } else {
        return obj.value.split(/\n/g).length-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.`function textareaCurLineNum(obj)
{
    return obj.value.split(/\n/g).length;
}` works properly.

Comment: Don't use browser sniffing! That makes it impossible for Opera to ever change behaviour to be consistent with other browsers without breaking sites.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on `\n` only. The way you wrote it - if I have:

```
first line \r\n
second line
```

this split will return 3, since it counts the nothingness between the `\r` and `\n` as a line.

A more robust solution will be to first normalise the text by replacing all `\r\n` (win) and just `\r` (mac) with `\n` and then splitting on `\n`.